# is there a way to modify an attribute of a DOM element directly with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know a way to shorten this:

```
$('.el').attr('src', $('.el').attr('src').replace('/subpath1/', '/subpath2/'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it with a callback function where you can get the old attribute value as the second argument.

```
$('.el').attr('src',function(i, oldSrc){
  return oldSrc.replace('/subpath1/', '/subpath2/');
})
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
$('.el').attr('src', (i, s) => s.replace('/subpath1/', '/subpath2/'))
```

---

You can reduce the code length using capturing group regex.

```
$('.el').attr('src', (i, s) => s.replace(/(\/subpath)1\//, '$12/'))
```

Comment: You beat me by few seconds

Comment: it is not much shorter. :/ is this considered as a best way?

Comment: Thank you for the different solutions. Good to know ES6 new function!

Comment: For a completely different reason this is even the **only** valid solution. If, for example you have multiple elements of class `el` each containing `/subpath1/` every elements src will use the first's match replaced source value. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7k40nkcn/

Answer (score 1):

You can also store your element in var first like so:

```
var el = $('.el');
el.attr('src', el.attr('src').replace('/subpath1/', '/subpath2/'))
```

So you won't need to crawl the DOM a second time.